# Make a new dataset that has the same variables and value types, but random observations based on a source dataset

Tags: r

I have five tables, each with between 20 to 30 variables and 1,500 to 2,300 observations.  I want to make a new dataset similar in values to the original dataset but not the same. Meaning if one variable is gender. I want the new dataset to have gender data, but the values would differ.

I'm unsure what functions to use or even how to search for some methods. My Google searches are coming up with how to make subsets of data, but I need new datasets with the same number of variables and observations with random values based on the values of the source dataset.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: I think you would need to be a bit more explicit about "based on the values of the source dataset". For example do you want the new dataset to have exactly the  same distribution of the values within each column, or a near approximation, or no approximation at all? Do you want the correlation structure across columns to be similar to the original frame, etc. Depending on how explicit you can make your question, this may or may not belong in this forum.

Comment: Searching "R package fake data" I found [this helpful blog post](https://rviews.rstudio.com/2020/09/09/fake-data-with-r/) that mentions quite a few options. It sounds like the `fakeR` package might be just what you're looking for--it's not on CRAN anymore but you could probably install an old version. Another package not mentioned in that article is [`wakefield`](https://github.com/trinker/wakefield).

Comment: @langtang Thank you. I would like it approximate.

Comment: Thank you, @GregorThomas! I'll look into these resources